# Function that detects the final part from the input string

Tags: python

I want a code snippet that detects the final part of an input to define what command to execute.

I am asking this like that because I have no clue of what to even start from. I've not tried anything, and I would like to know if its even possible before I start. My piece of code is what I know would work, but I want to make a lot of them, so I was wondering if you could possibly make it shorter than just adding the if's by hand, as if with a function.

```py
command = input()
if command == "add role_1"
     role = 1
```

Comment: not sure if `string.endswith()` helps, but it is quite hard to say what are you really after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will split the command string into its parts and give you 2 variables. `cmd` will be the string containing the command, and `arguments` will be a list of strings of the arguments.

So say the input is `"add role_1"`

`cmd` will be `"add"`

`arguments` will be `["role_1"]`

```py
command = input()
commandPieces = command.split(" ")
cmd = commandPieces[0]
arguments = commandPieces[1:]
```

Comment: So, I need to use `command.split("  ")` to split the input into 2 parts, cmd, which will be "add" and the arguments that can be ["role_1"], or ["role_2"] and all? I may need to search how to do this exactly since I didn't really understand the code example you gave me. What is that `commandPieces[0]` for cmd? Or the one for arguments?

Comment: Ok, so `command.split(" ")` will split the string by spaces. So for example if the string is `"add role_1 role_2"`, that will return the value `["add", "role_1", "role_2"]`. In my code example I stored this in commandPieces. I then take the first item in that list ("add") and assign it to the variable `cmd`. I do this by indexing `commandPieces`. I them slice the rest of the list and put it into the variable arguments. So `commandPieces[0]` will return `"add"` and `commandPieces[1:]` will return `["role_1", "role_2"]`.

Comment: `commandPieces[0]` indexes the list and returns the first argument

`commandPieces[1:]` slices the list and takes the second argument onwards and returns a list

Answer (score 0):

You just use `string[-1`] to get the last character of a `string`. Then, just convert it to an `int` to use it as a number.

An example:

```
mystr = "add role_1"
print(mystr[-1]) # Last character

role = int(mystr[-1])
print(role) # role = 1
```

Comment: Ok, I get what I need to do. But how should I replace the `[-1]` so that I can put more than a single character from the end, taking 3 for example?

Comment: Just change it to `int(mystr[-2:])` or `int(mystr[-3:])` depending on the size of characters from the end. As example, `mystr[-3:]` will take the last 3 characters.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this now.